# Rails associations nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-models

I have three tables that are created by a non rails application. The following models are just the associations for the tables.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
  has_many :locations, :through => :programs
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :client
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
  has_many :clients, :through => :programs
end
```

I would like a simpler way to list out all the programs by location for a client.

I thought the following code would work, but it returns all programs for that location, and that completely makes sense.

```
@client.locations.each do |location|
  <h2>location.name</h2>
  <ul>
   location.programs.each do |program|
   <li>program.name</li>
  end
  </ul>
end
```

I'm currently using

```
@client.locations.each do |location|
      <h2>location.name</h2>
      <ul>
       Program.where(:location_id => location.id, :client_id => @client.id).each do |program|
       <li>program.name</li>
      end
      </ul>
    end
```

But this is against MVC principals and is ugly.

I'm not sure how to write this code elegantly, and would appreciate input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `includes` method for eager loading the data. Also, using include for this situation will create a join query that will fetch only those programs which are related to both location and client.

```
@client.locations.includes(:programs).each do |location|
  <h2>location.name</h2>
  <ul>
    location.programs.each do |program|
      <li>program.name</li>
    end
  </ul>
end
```

Though you should avoid using database queries in view files. So you can move `@locations = @client.locations.includes(:programs)` to your controller action and use `@locations` in view to maintain the structure.

Comment: Using includes(:programs) still returns all the programs for all clients related to that location

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@client.programs.each do |program|
  <h2>program.location.name</h2>
  <ul>
      <li>program.name</li>
    end
  </ul>
end
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. What i'm looking for is 

<h2>USA</h2>
program_1
program_3
<h2>Canada</h2>
program_2
program_4

Comment: Then you can
@client.locations.each do |location|
      <h2>location.name</h2>
      <ul>
       location.programs.find_by_client(client).each do |program|
       <li>program.name</li>
      end
      </ul>
    end
made find_by_client scope in program model

Comment: There will be n+1 query problem with this suggestion. So we need to use eager loading here.

Comment: That's probably what i'm looking for. Manoj, could you give a quick example?